# How to pass whole object to intent in onChildClick in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, object, onclick, onclicklistener, expandablelistview

In GridView or simple ListView, I'm using this code to pass an object to a new activity and it works just fine:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Illusion i = (Illusion) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(IllusionsGridActivity.this, ViewIllusionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to do the same in Expandable list to child objects, but it doesn't work. It seems to accept only String values. So this doesn't work:

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Illusion i = (Illusion) parent.getItemAtPosition(childPosition);
            Intent intent = new Intent(IllusionsListActivity.this, ViewIllusionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item", i);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Is there a way how to pass whole object to a new activity inside this method?

Comment: Do you want to pass your custom class or childview?

Comment: I want to pass an object of my custom class, the target activity uses its attributes to display them in ImageViews and TextViews.

Comment: Is there a problem of retrieving an object? or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next code:

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        long packedPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        int flatPosition = parent.getFlatListPosition(packedPosition)
        Illusion i = (Illusion) parent.getItemAtPosition(flatPosition);
        Intent intent = new Intent(IllusionsListActivity.this, ViewIllusionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("item", i);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, this certainly does something, but only with the default order of items; when divided into categories, it shows incorrect data. (You know what I mean? It's quite hard for me to explain since I don't really know how your code is supposed to work.)

Comment: oh wait, I fixed the adapter used with this listview and now it seems that this actually works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Parcable.

In the first Activtiy

```
Illusion i = (Illusion) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent in = new Intent(IllusionsGridActivity.this,ViewIllusionActivity.class);
in.putExtra("key", i);
startActivity(in);
```

In the second Activtiy

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
User usr = (User) intent.getParcelableExtra("key");
```

In Illusion class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class User implements Parcelable {

    private long exampleValueLong;
    private int exampleValueInt;
    private String exampleValueString;
    private boolean exampleValueBool; 

    public User(){}

    // all getters and setters go here //...


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
      // ignore for now
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel pc, int flags) {
        pc.writeLong(exampleValueLong);
        pc.writeInt(exampleValueInt);
        pc.writeString(exampleValueString);
        pc.writeInt( exampleValueBool ? 1 :0 );
   }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<Illusion>() {

         public Illusion createFromParcel(Parcel pc) {
             return new Illusion(pc);
         }

         public Illusion[] newArray(int size) {
             return new Illusion[size];
         }
   };

   public Illusion(Parcel pc){
       exampleValueLong = pc.readLong();
       exampleValueInt  =  pc.readInt();
       exampleValueString  = pc.readString();
       exampleValueBool= ( pc.readInt() == 1 );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah my Illusion class is already implemented as Parcelable, the problem isn't there I guess